# Currency tab reflects 1ETH = $0.00

Tags: wallets, jaxx

I use the Jaxx wallet, I did reset the wallet as per the help function, due to my balances not updating.  My ETH balance is now reflecting but the currency tab does not update it reflects as 1 ETH = $0.00  wallet

Answer (score 2):

Issue in progress

https://mobile.twitter.com/Jaxx_Support/status/876834099587162112

Wait and see

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem as the currency balance was not updating the last few days. I did the reset and now it shows zero as the currency balance, but I can see the amount of ETH.

I submitted a support request to Jaxx but they have not yet answered. Seems this is a problem across Jaxx and not just for one user.